# Why doesn't the Text update when using @Binding?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The `Working` works as expected.

But using the `@Binding` in the `NotWorking` example, doesn't seem to update the `Text` control. Why doesn't the `@Binding` version work, what am I missing here?

Initial Launch:
[image: Initial Launch]

After Typing:
[image: After typing]

```
struct Working: View {
    //Binding from @State updates both controls
    @State private var text = "working"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("syncs to label...", text: $text)
            Text($text.wrappedValue)
        }
    }
}
struct NotWorking: View {
    //Using the @Binding only updates the TextField
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        //This does not works
        VStack {
            TextField("won't sync to label...", text: $text)
            Text($text.wrappedValue)
        }
    }
}

struct Working_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var text = "not working"
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            Working()
            NotWorking(text: $text)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Static `@State`s don't work.

Comment: Thanks. Was this in the docs or a video or something? Is there a common workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static `@State`s don't work. It's the fact that it being `static` means that the `struct` `Working_Previews` isn't mutated when `text` is changed, so it won't refresh.

We can test this by changing from a `PreviewProvider` to an actual `View`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State static var text = "not working"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Working()
            NotWorking(text: ContentView.$text)
        }
    }
}
```

This code gives the following runtime message:

> Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.

Comment: Thanks. So that `static` var doesn't mutate the `struct`. Is there something else that I can do to get this working for previews?

Comment: @joels I'm not sure, it would just be best to not use `static` with SwiftUI property wrappers. Do something more like your working example, where the `@State` is inside the view. Another option is that you can also use `.constant(...)` when you need to pass in a `Binding` for a preview - however this doesn't change the value, so is equivalent to this `static` `@State` you have in the not working example (but `.constant(...)` is much neater.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'm going to need access to the `text` property from parent views. That is why I'm trying to use @Binding instead of @State.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @George_E. I define @State in a wrapper view and display that for the preview. The `WrapperView` simply displays the control that I want to preview but it contains the State.

[image: Working]

```
struct Working_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    //Define the State in a wrapper view
    struct WrapperView: View {
        @State var text = "Preview is now working!!!"
        var body: some View {
            NotWorking(text: $text)
        }
    }

    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            Working()
            //Don't display the view that needs the @Binding
            //NotWorking(text: $text)
            //Use the WrapperView that has @State and displays the view I want to preview.
            WrapperView()
        }
    }
}
```